# print(eval("print(2+3)")) prints 2 different answer

Tags: python-3.x, eval

I was doing basic python Hackerrank challanges when there was this challange; get the input line as string and pass it to eval and print it. As an example given input was

> print(2+3)

When I executed the same code as in title it printed 2 different answers. Those were

> 5
>  None

Is this happening because of Hackerrank's compiler or is it a common thing in python?

Edit: I am curious because I thought eval returns only 1 thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second value is what the function evaluates to, i.e. the return value of the function. The return value of the `print()` function is `None`. Thus, your `eval()` call will evaluate `print(2+3)`, which evaluates to `None`. The 'side-effect' is that the `print()` function  prints some values, which occurs *before* the function return.

Comment: So where does this 'side-effect' comes from? From outer `print()` or `print()` in the `eval()` ?

Comment: In the `print()` function, first, the function displays some text onto the screen; then, it returns `None`. So that is why you see the text displayed first, then `None` is displayed.

Comment: Now I got it, thank you!